# Dependency injection management with 'Unit of work' and 'Repository' design patterns using SqlConnection instance

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dapper

A lot of time, I face a situation where I want to execute a number of statements without re-opening a connection.

So my practice so far is to create a 'unit of work' class, open a connection and pass it to all the repositories.

Here is an example of code that I have:

```
public class BasicEmailUnitOfWork : IBasicEmailUnitOfWork
{
        private readonly IDNTConnectionFactory _conn; 

        public BasicEmailUnitOfWork(IDNTConnectionFactory connection)
        {
            _conn = connection; 
        }

        public (string, string, string, string, string) RenderEmailTemplate(string emailTemplateEventName, int userId)
        {
            string userPhone = String.Empty;
            string userEmail = String.Empty;
            string emailTitletranslatedContent = String.Empty;
            string emailBodytranslatedContent = String.Empty;
            string smstranslatedContent = String.Empty;

            try
            {
                IDbConnection connectionDb = _conn.GetConnection();

                IEmailSMSTemplateRepository _emailSMSTemplateRepository = new EmailSMSTemplateRepository(connectionDb);

                IUserInformationRepository _userInformationRepository = new UserInformationRepository(connectionDb);

                List<EmailSMSTemplateTDO> emailSmsesList = _emailSMSTemplateRepository.GetAllTemplates(emailTemplateEventName);

                UserInfoDTO userInfoDTO = _userInformationRepository.GetAllInformation(userId);
                userPhone = userInfoDTO.Phone;
                userEmail = userInfoDTO.Email;

                foreach (EmailSMSTemplateTDO emailTemplate in emailSmsesList)
                {
                    emailTitletranslatedContent = TranslateContent(connectionDb, userInfoDTO, emailTemplate.EmailTitle);

                    emailBodytranslatedContent = TranslateContent(connectionDb, userInfoDTO, emailTemplate.EmailBody);

                    if (emailTemplate.IsSMS)
                        smstranslatedContent = TranslateContent(connectionDb, userInfoDTO, emailTemplate.SMSBody);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                _conn.CloseConnection();
            }

            return (userPhone, userEmail,emailTitletranslatedContent, emailBodytranslatedContent, smstranslatedContent);
    }

    private string TranslateContent(IDbConnection connectionDb, UserInfoDTO userInfoDTO, string content)
    {
            InterpreterContext intContext = new InterpreterContext();
            intContext.user = userInfoDTO;
            intContext.Content = content;

            IExpression emailSMSContentInterpreter = new EmailSMSContentInterpreter(connectionDb);
            emailSMSContentInterpreter.Interpret(intContext);
            return emailSMSContentInterpreter.BodyContentOutPut;
    }
}
```

Although, I can unit test the repositories without a problem, I have 2 dependencies in the function: `EmailSMSTemplateRepository` and `UserInformationRepository`.

What is the best practice? What other way is there to share the connection, take note also that I need some class to dispose of the connection when the object is being disposed or if there is an error.

By the way, I use Dapper for the application, same micro-ORM that was used to build this site.

Comment: Why RenderEmailTemplate inside UnitOfWork? Unit of work has 2 main duties: `Gathering` some repositories to do a task,  And `begin/commit transactions` if necessary. Why not creating an `EmailService` with `RenderEmailTemplate` method, and injecting `BasicEmailUnitOfWork` to it's constructor? One more thing: Disposing an object is duty of a class that created it. Here,  `IDNTConnectionFactory` is injected to your class from `elsewhere`. Hence, the elsewhere should worry about disposing it. not `BasicEmailUnitOfWork`. If you use Dependecy Injection, it is the duty of framework itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past I've approached this via the use of a Connection Factory -> Data Session -> Unit of Work -> Repository pattern.

Something like -

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    Guid Id { get; }
    IDbConnection Connection { get; }
    IDbTransaction Transaction { get; }
    void Begin();
    void Commit();
    void Rollback();
}

public sealed class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    internal UnitOfWork(IDbConnection connection)
    {
        _id = Guid.NewGuid();
        _connection = connection;
    }

    private readonly IDbConnection _connection = null;
    private IDbTransaction _transaction = null;
    private readonly Guid _id;

    IDbConnection IUnitOfWork.Connection => _connection;
    IDbTransaction IUnitOfWork.Transaction => _transaction;
    Guid IUnitOfWork.Id => _id;

    public void Begin()
    {
        _transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        _transaction.Commit();
        Dispose();
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
        _transaction.Rollback();
        Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _transaction?.Dispose();
        _transaction = null;
    }
}

//define enum's that describe various databases you might want to connect to
//the db type/engine is an implementation detail handled by the connection factory
public enum DatabaseInstance
{
    YourDatabase,
    SomeOtherDatabase,
    AThirdDatabase
}

//abstracts the 'how do i connect to the database?' question
public interface IDbConnectionFactory
{
    IDbConnection GetConnection(DatabaseInstance database);
}

//for instance - 
public class SqlDbConnectionFactory : IDbConnectionFactory
{
    public IDbConnection GetConnection(DatabaseInstance database)
    {
        //return a IDbConnection for a given DatabaseInstance value
        //possible implementations could be storing a DatabaseInstance->Connectionstring map dictionary that is populated in the constructor
    }
}

public interface IDataAccessSession : IDisposable
{
    IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; }

    void StartSession(DatabaseInstance databaseInstance);
}

//one possible implementation - use a connection factory and requested instance to create an IUnitOfWork for consumers to use
public sealed class DataAccessSession : IDataAccessSession
{
    private IDbConnection _connection = null;

    private readonly IDbConnectionFactory _dbConnectionFactory;

    public DalSession(IDbConnectionFactory dbConnectionFactory)
    {
        _dbConnectionFactory = dbConnectionFactory;
    }

    public void StartSession(DatabaseInstance databaseInstance)
    {
        _connection = _dbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(databaseInstance);
        _connection.Open();
        UnitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(_connection);
    }
    
    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; private set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        UnitOfWork.Dispose();
        _connection.Dispose();
    }
}

//then there's an extension method (in practice a helper overload per DatabaseInstance as well
//starts a session, passes the unit of work to the consumer task, commit/rollsback, and then disposes
public static class DataAccessSessionExtensions
{
    public static async Task<T> RunTransactionAsync<T>(this IDataAccessSession dataAccessSession, DatabaseInstance instance, Func<IUnitOfWork, Task<T>> functionToRun, bool rollbackOnException=false)
    {
        dataAccessSession.StartSession(instance);
        dataAccessSession.UnitOfWork.Begin();
        try
        {

            var result = await functionToRun(dataAccessSession.UnitOfWork);
            dataAccessSession.UnitOfWork.Commit();

            return result;
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            if(rollbackOnException)
                dataAccessSession.UnitOfWork.Rollback();
            else
                dataAccessSession.UnitOfWork.Commit();
            throw;
        }
    }
}

//then in your dependency injection container (asp.net core here)
....
//if  you needed to say connect to mongo for one and sql for another this would need a bit further refinement as the MS DI Api doesn't handle that well, you'd need to do something like pass collections of connection factory/instance->connections instead as one possible solution
//this can be a singleton as it doesn't store live connections, just how to map requests to new connections
services.AddSingleton<IDbConnectionFactory>(i => new SqlDbConnectionFactory(/*pass in a values for connection strings per data base instance defined*/)); 
//should be scoped so that a new instance is created/disposed per DI request         
services.AddScoped<IDalSession, DalSession>();
....

//finally usage would be like so
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    private readonly IDataAccessSession _dataAccessSession;
    private readonly ISomeRepo _someRepo;
    Private readonly ISomeOtherRepo _someOtherRepo

    public SomeService (IDataAccessSession dataAccessSession, ISomeRepo someRepo, ISomeOtherRepo someOtherRepo)
    {
        _dataAccessSession = dataAccessSession;
        _someRepo = someRepo;
        _someOtherRepo = someOtherRepo;
    }

    // at this point all needed repo's are handed a single UnitOfWork that represents the connection and transaction and a session that will clean up afterwards 
    public async Task<SomeResult> DoSomeThing(string param1, int param2)
    {
        var result = await _dataAccessSession.RunTransactionAsync(DatabaseInstance.Whatever, async uow =>
        {
            //critical - forget this and things will go boom
            _someRepo.UnitOfWork = uow;
            _someOtherRepo.UnitOfWork = uow;

           var repo1Value = await _someRepo.SomeAction(param1);
           var repo2Value = await _someOtherRepo.GetAThing(param2);
           
           return new SomeResult(repo1Value, repo2Value);
        });
        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

One weak point was that I never did find a better way to pass the unit of work to the repo layer besides requiring them to implement a receiving property and then populated it before use. It means it would be easy for a dev to forget that step and run into errors.

```
public interface IHasUnitOfWork 
{
    IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }
}

public interface IDataRepo : IHasUnitOfWork
{
}

public interface ISomeRepo : IDataRepo
{
    Task UpdateSomethingAsync();
}

//at the time of implementing the repo the promise is that UnitOfWork will be non-null with a valid open connection 
//that is ready to exec against and that if a sql exception is thrown a rollback will be initiated (if flag is set)
//though note that if multiple repos are sharing this unit of work and a different one throws, this repo's calls will also rollback as it considers all actions to be under a single transaction scope per IDataAccessSession
public SomeRepo : ISomeRepo 
{ 
    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    public async Task UpdateSomethingAsync()
    {
        await UnitOfWork.Connection.ExecuteAsync("sproc", .....);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, you pass unit of work to the repos through a property instead of a constructor.

Comment: Right because the repo objects are given by the DI container through interfaces. The consuming code is decoupled from any implementation types. I consider this a pretty big weak point though. Perhaps the repo layer should have accepted the unit of work  object as a parameter to each call or something as this is sort of 'pit of failure' rather then 'pit of success'.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, there is a lot of danger in keeping a connection open and reusing it, especially across multiple user contexts. The chance of inserting wrong is very high.

As for your statement "without re-opening a connection", what is the purpose of not "reopening". I ask this as SQL connections are not actually disposed of when you dispose them. The connection is cleared out and goes into a pool underneath the hood. What this means is you are not incurring any overhead "re-instantiating" the object from the pool. Your code has the safety of disposal, but there is no overhead. NOTE I am assuming the idea of having object creation overhead is the perceived issue.

This is why Microsoft has you shut them down every time, but has made the pool underneath the hood. Yes, the pool objects can time out, but you are throwing things at it quickly enough it will not reach the time out (default == 30 seconds).

NOTE: Even Dapper does not do anything special to really destroy the connection object (i.e. they did not circumvent .NET and reinvent the wheel).

Following the above, the best practice is to allow the objects to Dispose and go back into pool. I know it seems a bit counterintuitive, but once you realize there is an internal pool object, it makes sense.

If you want a thought experiment about running multiple commands in a row, you can consider creating the commands as units of work and rapidly feeding them. You would need a bit of command management in your repo, but it is sounder than creating a single connection and waiting until you are finished with the object to Dispose (as a failure to Dispose, in some instances, could be BAAAAADDDD).

Comment: But if I create a new connection in every repository, it takes more processing time than using the same connection. What If I wanted to implement a single transaction. I cant open a few connects and roll back or commit all of them while each batch of statements belonging to a different repo or class.

Comment: @LastGrip *"it takes more processing time"* How do you know? Have you measured?

Comment: @LastGrip *"I cant open a few connects and roll back or commit all of them while each batch of statements belonging to a different repo or class"* Yes you can. Surround all the operations with a `TransactionScope`.

Comment: @LastGrip - What causes extra processing time? The instantiation is eliminated, which would be milliseconds at most. The pulling from the pool might take a microsecond, but if your solution requires that performance level, why aren't you using something that is even faster, like stored procedures. Additionally, if you are doing transactions, then chaining works, but a stored procedure is even more efficient as the entire transaction takes place in the database.